# $A^2=AB+BA$. Prove that $\det(AB-BA)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be two $3\times 3$ matrices with complex entries, such that $A^2=AB+BA$. Prove that $\det(AB-BA)=0$

Nice problem, and I want to find a solution.

$AB-BA=A^2-2BA=(A-2B)A$ so if $|A|=0$ we have done, if $|A| \not=0$ I can't prove.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120418/how-to-show-that-a2-abba-implies-detab-ba-0-for-3-times3-matrices

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\det(AB-BA)&= \det(A^2-2BA)\\
&= \det(A-2B)\det(A) \\
&= \det(A)\det(A-2B) \\
&= \det(A^2-2AB) \\
&= \det(BA-AB) \\
&= (-1)^3 \det(AB-BA) \\
&= -\det(AB-BA)
\end{align}$$
So $$\det(AB-BA)=0$$

Comment: I get the trick. Use the fact that matrices "commute under determinants". +1

Comment: nice. the first equality holds because $A^2 - 2AB = (AB+BA) - 2AB = AB - BA.$ i don't if it helps to add this step to yours. i had to think about it for a while.

Comment: @abel I just added that step.